# Gear: Stats and rating

Tags: the-secret-world

I didn't find a good/exact explanation on this so:

- How much rating (e.g. crit rating/penetration rating) is needed for 1% of the stat?
- How much hit rating is required? (cap for pve/pvp?)
- How does attack/heal rating influence my performance?
- How is combat power exactly calculated out of my stats?
- Is there a cap on certain stats? (e.g. crit)

Since I like to max out a game, I like to be able to calculate gear and optimal stats. (e.g. balance between crit and crit power for maximum dps) But for doing this I need to know how the game works/calculates things.

Comment: I read somewhere that the cap was 440?

Comment: @Lyrion On which stat(s)? Could you please try to provide a source?

Comment: My guess is crit, pen and hit. But not sure, ill go look for it tonight.

Comment: did the answer below answer your question?

Comment: @JerryRox Seems a little premature on the bounty award; there's been no time to vet accuracy or even utility.

Comment: oops... I guess I still have to learn a lot on this website! ^^

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a site that explains the stats themselves can be found [here.](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=50017) It'll just allow people to see full details on them.

---

> How much rating (e.g. crit rating/penetration rating) is needed for 1% of the stat?

As far as I could tell via forum entries and blog posts the answer varies. But there is a forum post [right here](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=51071) that says

> Amount of Rating needed to reduce damage by 1% is between 23 and 35 in this sample.

This seems to be the same throughout all stats.

---

I thought that this may be of some assistance when it comes to [damage.](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=65533) Lower down it explains what can increase your damage. The entire thread is all about healing and balancing that with attacks. It also explains how to glyph (which is handy).

> Is there a cap on certain stats? (e.g. crit)?

Lyrion said that the cap for critical/penetration and hit was 440. This is false. [This forum](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=60384) shows users who have experimented and have found that there is actually no cap.

---

> How is combat power exactly calculated out of my stats?

Unfortunately there is no finite answer in this. After searching on this topic for about an hour. This is what I have concluded: Your stats are extremely loosely related to the 23-35 points above.

> How much hit rating is required? (cap for pve/pvp?)

This is your last question. However it was tricky to answer. The forums are vague with this, always seeming to answer it but actually switching to a new question. But [in here](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?p=1238173) scroll down to look at sorrah's answer. I think it'll somewhat explain the hit rating requirements.

---

All in all your question can still be expanded upon. Since this exceeds the limit of characters possible in a comment I made it an answer. Hope this helps.